# I get an error while storing data to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mysql2

I am using the npm module **mysql2**
Here is the code:

```
var values = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'https://ne.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF_%E0']];
    con.query(
      "INSERT INTO urlparse (title, description, author, keywords, url) VALUES ?",
      [values],
      function(err, result) { 
        if (err) throw err;
      }
    );
  });
```

And here is the error I get:

```
                 ^
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''https://ne.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF_%E0' at line 1
    at Packet.asError (/rbd/pnpm-volume/12c7da94-52ca-491c-a99d-4962bc1f1e80/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
    at Query.execute (/rbd/pnpm-volume/12c7da94-52ca-491c-a99d-4962bc1f1e80/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/12c7da94-52ca-491c-a99d-4962bc1f1e80/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/12c7da94-52ca-491c-a99d-4962bc1f1e80/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/rbd/pnpm-volume/12c7da94-52ca-491c-a99d-4962bc1f1e80/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/12c7da94-52ca-491c-a99d-4962bc1f1e80/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:226:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your driver supports expanding `?` into multiple values? You may need to add one `?` per column.

Comment: You are passing an array of array for the values in the query, try with `values` instead of `[values]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of array for the values in the query
Try with `values` instead of `[values]`

```
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
'https://ne.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF_%E0'];

con.query(
 "INSERT INTO urlparse (title, description, author, keywords, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
 values, // Array of values here
 function(err, result) { 
   if (err) throw err;
 }
);
```